# CDN with self update options

Tags: web-services

I'm searching for server/ cnd / image hosting with option to self update content:

1. user hits start page
2. all images load like: http://cdn.server.com/?image=path_to_image_on_my_server
3. CND server checks if image ws downloaded from my serwer and:

3a. download it and serve

3b. serve it

In short I wan't to store my images on another serwer like CDN without puting them every time I add new image on my portal.

Answer (score 0):

Most of them do this by default. I used the following and that wasn't a problem there.
Although, if you want, you can update it manually, the default is update by request.

http://www.cdn77.com

https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: Well it is hard to recommend websites without posting their links.
What would you have me do? Tell him about all those fancy hosters out there without posting a link?

Comment: Well, if these hosting providers are not available anymore, then it won't help him to know what they can do.
I do understand the concept of not linking, but in this case it wouldn't make sense to describe providers that can do that, but not link to them! It's not like a tutorial!
Seriously: He wanted to get tips for hosting providers, who can do what he is looking for.